# Array passed to opencl kernel incorrect

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencl, pyopencl, amd-gpu

I'm a trying hard on AMD Radeon RX570 Series' OpenCL.

I'm trying to pass a array of argument onto OpenCL kernel but unsuccessful.

Here is the code

**is_prime.py**

```py
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import math
import pyopencl as cl
from pyopencl import mem_flags as mf
from pyopencl import map_flags as mapf

global prime_number
prime_number = np.array([2]).astype(np.uint64)

is_prime_prg_code = open("kernel/is_prime.cl").read()
global _is_prime_prg
_is_prime_prg = None
global cl_ctx
cl_ctx = cl.create_some_context()
global cl_queue
cl_queue = cl.CommandQueue(cl_ctx)

def _is_prime(number):
    global _is_prime_prg
    global cl_ctx
    global cl_queue
    if _is_prime_prg is None:
        _is_prime_prg = cl.Program(cl_ctx, is_prime_prg_code).build()

    res = np.array([0]).astype(np.uint64)
    res_buffer = cl.Buffer(cl_ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=res)
    prime_buffer = cl.Buffer(cl_ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=prime_number)
    
    arg = np.array([number, len(prime_number)]).astype(np.uint64)
    print(arg)
    arg_buffer = cl.Buffer(cl_ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.USE_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=arg)
    _is_prime_prg.is_prime(cl_queue, (1,), None, arg_buffer, prime_buffer,  res_buffer)
    cl_queue.finish()
    arr, event = cl.enqueue_map_buffer(cl_queue, res_buffer, mapf.READ, 0, res.shape, dtype=np.uint64)
    return arr[0];

_is_prime(3)
```

**is_prime.cl**

```c
__kernel void is_prime(
    __global const long * arg, 
    __global long * prime_array,
    __global int * res
    )
{
    ulong * number = (ulong *)arg[0];
    ulong * prime_array_len = (ulong *)arg[1];
    int ret = 1;
    int iter = 0;
    printf("number = %d prime_array_len %d\n", *arg, *prime_array_len);
    for (iter = 0; iter < *prime_array_len; iter++)
    {
        long prime = prime_array[iter];
        if(prime * prime > *number){
            break;
        }
        if(*number % prime == 0){
            ret = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
    *res = ret;
}
```

And here is the output result

```
[3 1]

number = 3 prime_array_len 0
```

What am I doing wrong here?